# Adventure across planets/galaxies; small band of brothers vs evil empire with a unique currency system

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a series of books back in the late 70's early 80's, quite an adventure. I seem to recall it was at least 6 books in the series.  The overarching storyline was "a small band of brothers" running from an overwhelmingly large government/empire/organization from planet to planet across galaxies in an old/aging starship constantly needing repairs.

The one storyline that I can clearly remember involves the currency that was used.  Money quite literally grew on trees.  There was a planet - almost like a game preserve - that you could land on where you could go to gather money.  You could safely land outside the fenced off zone and prepare to enter like the rest of the desperate people in the same boat.  You could keep whatever you could carry if you survived.

The value of the currency depended upon its color and its abundance i.e. the deeper you went from the fence line the less abundant and more rare the colors, the more valuable the currency.  However, the money was guarded by a vicious and cunning race of aliens (almost like Predators - before they existed) that
possessed physical capabilities far beyond humans.

As well as being fiercely protective of their planet they enjoyed letting people push deeper into the preserve so they could hunt them at their leisure. The heroes made a desperate attempt to gain the huge sums of money needed to repair their ship which provided a gripping depiction of their time in the preserve, their struggle to survive being hunted and their near death escape.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Questions: Language? Country? Do you remember anything about the books themselves, such as covers?

Answer (score 5):

The part about the preserve sounds an awful lot like Jack Vance's "Planet of Adventure"  series, in particular the book "The Dirdir".  The hero and his friends enter a hunting preserve of the Dirdir, there to harvest "sequins" that grow in "nodes" close to the ground.  The more mature nodes have a deeper color, and are more valuable.  If caught by the Dirdir, they are captured and eaten.  But there are only 4 books in the series, and your other plot points don't match up.

Comment: On wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_Adventure